# How to update a review that had old commits before it?

Tags: git, review-board, rbtools

I ask for help with updating the review on the Review Board

[image]

I forked from master, made a few commits on my branch, and published review 1. Then I closed that review

Then I made another commit on the same branch and published review_2 with the command

```
rbt post id1 id2
```

id1 is the id of the commit posted in review_1, id2 is the id of the commit posted in review_2

Then I made another commit (edits to comments), and I want to publish it in review_2

I tried using the command

```
rbt post -r id_review_2
```

but this command doesn’t work the way I want (it also uploads changes from review_1 to review_2)

I tried using the command

```
rbt post id1 id3 -r id_review_2
```

but it breaks with an error *CRITICAL: Too many revisions specified*

Please tell me which command I need to use for my task!